# Easy Digital Downloads (Recurring Payments) if User Has Active Subscription show Something

Tags: php, wordpress, easy-digital-downloads

I need to show something only to users with active subscriptions, im using the edd recurring payments plugin, I found this is their docs

```
$subscriber->has_active_subscription()
```

But im not sure how to make use of it to show something only to users with active subscriptions.

So i will be adding this code in my archive.php file and show extra php code for active users.

Comment: Im trying to look at the logic here https://github.com/easydigitaldownloads/library/blob/ebe5d3f621ec2e8d34dd1b784f8336f6a901ce8b/_extensions/recurring-payments/edd-subscription-status.html but it seems a bit complicated, might be useful to check this too. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that code you found is part of the OOP class used by Easy Digital Downloads. Their docs are here: https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/1160-recurring-payments-developer-eddrecurringsubscriber

What you'd need to do is something like:

```
$my_user = get_current_user_id(); //grab current user

$subscriber = new EDD_Recurring_Subscriber( $my_user, true ); //pass user id to EDD class

//The EDD class will return its own user object, and on that you can do your check from the question:
if ($subscriber->has_active_subscription()) {
echo 'some special message for users with subscriptions';
} else {
//do something else
}
```

Watch out though, because that method will return true both if user has an active subscription and if he/she has a cancelled subscription (but false if subscription has expired). That may or may not be what you want.

I don't have EDD so haven't tested this but I hope it at least gets you started.